# .NET: Dependencies of referenced project are not installed in main project

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, chromium-embedded

I have the following projects:

[VS 2022 Solution explorer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDXdd.png)

MyConsoleApplication (.NET 6) has a project reference to MyClassLibrary (.NET Core 3.1).
MyClassLibrary has two package references:

```
    <PackageReference Include="cef.redist.x64" Version="113.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore" Version="113.1.40" />
```

The nuget package `cef.redist.x64` contains (among many other things):

```
CEF
 ╚ locales
    ╚ af.pak
```

When I build MyConsoleApplication, the "locales" folder is not included in its output folder (\MyConsoleApplication\bin\Debug\net6.0\runtimes\win-x64\native\locales\af.pak), unless the following direct reference is included also in MyConsoleApplication:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore" Version="113.1.40" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I am trying to figure it out why the sub-dependency is not treated as a direct dependency. Why I get a different result by referencing it explicitly. I am not sure if this is a particularity of these specific (cef) nuget packages, or a general .NET rule I don't know about.

Please find a zip with the sample solution here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_bTZ2_LCtDjcFBD2Ki2xWh5wE5o838bF?usp=sharing .
Thank you.

I expect that dependencies (`CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore`) of a referenced project (`MyClassLibrary`) will be treated as direct references (`MyConsoleApplication` -> `CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore`), and that including such a direct reference (`MyConsoleApplication` -> `CefSharp.OffScreen.NETCore`) will make no difference to the output folder.

Comment: What you describe is the current expected behavior. Your expectation is not how it currently works.

Comment: But when I install nuget packages in my .NET application, their dependencies are automatically installed. Not in this case. What's the difference?

Comment: A `ProjectReference` points to another project. The referenced project's assembly, files named to match the assembly (e.g. the .pdb file), and linkage dependencies of the assembly will be copied to the current project. But `ProjectReference` doesn't know about and doesn't handle any `PackageReference`s in the referenced project. A linkage dependency that actually comes from a package may be copied but the package as a whole is not copied. When a project contains a `ProjectReference`, the `PackageReference`s in the referenced project do not become "direct references" in the referencing project.

Comment: I hedged in my first comment by saying "currently" a lot. There are thorny backwards compatibility issues but it does appear that this issue and other issues with dependency handling in MSBuild will be addressed by the multiple development teams that are involved.